# Class not found Die and Dump environment variable keys

Tags: php, laravel

I am going through a laravel tutorial and the section I am stuck on is called "The Service Container" Basically I just grab a environment variable and spit it out to the page with a dd() die and dump. However I get a `class not found` error. I know it must be a small bug, but cant quite figure it out. I tried running `composer dump-autoload` with no luck.

Here is my code

`routes/web.php`

```
App::bind('App\Billing\Stripe', function(){

    return new \App\Billing\Stripe(config('services.stripe.secret'));

});

$stripe = App::make('App\Billing\Stripe');

dd($stripe);
```

`app/billing/Stripe.php`

```
namespace App\Billing;

class Stripe{

  protected $key;

  public function __construct($key){

    $this->key = $key;

  }

}
```

Comment: rename `billing` folder to capital case. as psr-4 the autoloading standard is case-sensitive

Comment: Do you want to make that the answer and I can select it, so trivial. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need here for dump-autoload because you're creating a new namespace inside psr-4 confiugred folder `app`.

The solution is to rename the folder `billing` to a capital case, because laravel uses composer autoload following psr-4 standard which states that namespace matches the folder name in a case sensitive way.

Note : there are alternative autoloading schemes provided by composer that may need `composer dump-autoload` or editing `composer.json` when a new file is created